# Pushing with the the last commit to git

Tags: git

Let's say that I fixed an issue but I don't want to add a new commit. Is it technically possible to push changes without any new commit? (As part of previous commit?) If possible, how would the git log be affected with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it technically possible to push changes without any new commit

No. Commits are the *only* things that Git deals in, and they cannot be modified. You could *replace* the most recent commit with a commit that includes the fix (using `--amend`), but that would still be a new and different commit (and pushing it would be very bad if this is shared history).

Discovering bugs and fixing them in a new commit is what Git is all about. Do not try to subvert it. *Use* Git, don't *fight* it.

Comment: I just posted the nearly identical answer but you beat me by some number of seconds... deleting mine. :D

Comment: @TTT Sorry about that!